# Attaching horizontal and vertical scrollbar to the same widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-scrollbar

I want to create a viewport that could be horizontally and vertically scrolled. I am able to achieve this by using two nested SingleScrollChildView. The problem is that the horizontal scrollbar is not attached to the viewport as desired but rather it is attached/present at the bottom vertically which is expected. Is there a way to achieve such a behavior? Please be gentle as I am still learning this framework. Here is the code snippet:

```
Scrollbar(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Scrollbar(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: CustomViewPort(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: check `InteractiveViewer`

Comment: I want to be able to scroll both horizontally and vertically with  horizontal and vertical scrollbar attached to the viewing area(viewport)

Comment: any luck with a final solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[Bidirectional scrolling with fixed scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onCoy.gif)

I used [adaptive_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_scrollbar) v2.1.0 to get this result.

Source Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:adaptive_scrollbar/adaptive_scrollbar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Bidirectional Scrollbars',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _verticalScrollController = ScrollController();
    final _horizontalScrollController = ScrollController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 700,
        child: AdaptiveScrollbar(
          underColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.3),
          sliderDefaultColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
          sliderActiveColor: Colors.grey,
          controller: _verticalScrollController,
          child: AdaptiveScrollbar(
            controller: _horizontalScrollController,
            position: ScrollbarPosition.bottom,
            underColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.3),
            sliderDefaultColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
            sliderActiveColor: Colors.grey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _verticalScrollController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _horizontalScrollController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 16.0),
                  child: DataTable(
                    showCheckboxColumn: true,
                    columns: [
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Name'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Name'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                    ],
                    rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
                      20,
                      (int index) => DataRow(
                        cells: <DataCell>[
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                        ],
                        onSelectChanged: (bool? value) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The Flutter team announced that they are developing an official solution for this problem here's the video [Preview: Two-dimensional scrolling in Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDZ0LPQq-n8), Flutter 3.13 is out and it has added TwoDimensional scrolling foundation, more info in [What’s new in Flutter 3.13](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-13-479d9b11df4d), and it is also updating data tables to use this new 2D Scrolling, with some other improvements, the progress can be seen in GitHub  [2D Scrolling • flutter](https://github.com/orgs/flutter/projects/32).